# How can I get back the Tools menu in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I was fiddling around with the menu bar via `Tools->Customize` (the menu bar seems way bloated in this iteration) and accidentally removed the `Tools` menu itself!

Is there a failsafe to get back into this dialog or otherwise restore the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't made any changes to the toolbar that you want to keep, you could try resetting it.

Right click in the toolbar....`Customize`...`Commands`...`Reset All`.

Comment: Got it! It took a while--the `Customize` entry is way at the bottom of the context menu and on my low-res monitor I actually had to scroll to see it. Thanks!